# How can I achieve 3 biohazards with the 'Black Death' scenario in Plague Inc

Tags: plague-inc

I've had a reasonable amount of success with Plague Inc, and can reliably beat the 'normal' diseases on mega-brutal.

However I remain flummoxed by the Black Death scenario. I've tried several times now, and still haven't managed to get that magic triple-biohazard victory. Even with wiping out the population of the planet in under a year, I still find I don't quite manage it.

Can anyone suggest a modestly reliable strategy for doing this? (A degree of luck required is fine, I've already tried about 50 times).